# What does open quote expected for "android:id" in XML?

Tags: android, xml

```
         '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
          <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:background="@drawable/droid_background" >
          <TextView
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:gravity="center_horizontal"
           android:text="@string/hello"
           android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
           android:textStyle="bold" />
          <GridView 
           android:id=”@+id/videoGrdVw”
           android:layout_width=”fill_parent”
           android:layout_height=”fill_parent”
           android:numColumns=”auto_fit”
           android:verticalSpacing=”5dip”
           android:horizontalSpacing=”5dip”
           android:columnWidth=”80dip”
           android:stretchMode=”columnWidth”
           android:gravity=”center”/>      
          </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got fancy quotes mixed in with regular plain old quotes - replace the `”`s with `"`s and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's a strange problem with the quotes that you've posted. Some of them are of a different type than the others - look at the ones in the GridView. I would try changing them to be the same as the quotes up above and see if that helps.